# Jupyter Notebook won't launch

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am having trouble launching Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda Navigator. When I click launch my terminal opens with the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 58, in <module>
    raise ImportError(_("The Jupyter Notebook requires tornado >= 5.0, but you have %s") % tornado.version)
ImportError: The Jupyter Notebook requires tornado >= 5.0, but you have 4.5.3

Saving session...completed.

[Process completed]
```

I am not sure what is going on, I was able to launch Jupyter Notebook earlier in the day. Any solutions? I am using a macOS Monterey

Comment: It tells you what's wrong, doesn't it? Upgrade the Tornado version with `pip install --upgrade tornado`

Comment: I've done this and I still get the same message

Comment: Clearly not if you still get the same error. Make sure the `pip` package path is the same as the one used by the notebook's kernel; but your question does not contain nearly enough detail to determine what's installed where and how. Since you seem to be using `conda`, maybe search for questions related to upgrading `tornado` (or packages generally) in there.

Comment: This is what I got after trying to upgrade tornado: "Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: tornado in /Library/Python/3.8/site-packages (6.1)"

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the tornado version as stated in the logs. Do:

```
pip install tornado
```

Comment: It's already installed; you need to request an upgrade with `--upgrade` and possibly a version requirement.